# Node v0.10.36 showing prototype of an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Back in the day, I could do `Array.prototype` and it would show me the properties of the prototype member of the `Array` object. Even doing `console.dir(Array.prototype)` does not work in Node, however, it does work in the browser. Is there a new API that can show me the properties?

Comment: console.dir(Array.prototype) not working in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you.  Browser consoles usually have interactive displays for objects.  The node repl does not have the same feature, so you have to do the below to get a similar effect.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype)
```